# How to calculate the current output of a mosfet?

Tags: mosfet, circuit-analysis

Suppose one know \$V_{gate}, V_{Drain}\$ with \$V_{souce} \$ connect to a resistor \$R\$ and then connect to the ground. 
The [aspects of the mosfet](https://www.infineon.com/dgdl/irfz44npbf.pdf?fileId=5546d462533600a40153563b3a9f220d) was also known.

How to calculate the linear portion of the output current? i.e. the relatively linear current output where it's not in saturation region, and the voltage on the resistor?

Comment: You can read it off figure 1 in the datasheet you linked to (assuming 25 C junction temperature).

Comment: Or get a SPICE model for your device and simulate it.

Comment: @ThePhoton Thank you. But the figure 1 was in logarithm scale and the coefficient wasn't clear. I want to be able to actually calculate the current in program. Also, I want to know if there's a slight voltage difference (dispassion) between drain and souse pin.

Comment: The vertical scale is very clear. 1 A is the lowest value shown. 1000 A is the top of the graph. If you want to know about slight differences, then the SPICE route is the best choice. But remember there are also manufacturing variations from part to part that aren't captured in the SPICE model any more than in the typical performance curve on the datasheet.

Comment: Vds is not reasonably called "a slight difference" - it is a major factor in device dissipation and a major reason for consulting Figs 1 & 2. | For a given Vgs, Vds is related to Rds. V = IR = Ids x Rds. Atypical value for Rds in a given situation is in turn calculated from Fig 1. ie all roads lead to the graphical model in fig 1 or an analytical model in SPICE, or of your making. From Fig 1 you can see that below some "knee" value Rds is almost constant with varying Ids for a given value of Vgs  and that after the knee a new much higher and somewhat less constant Rds occurs. This could be ...

Comment: ... modelled empirically, but it is probably already handled as well as you are going to get in the SPICE model. | Note that graphs show typical results subject to production tolerances and any stated conditions.